# The type cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfsbuild

On TFS build machine, for one of my unit tests I get this error message.

**System.ArgumentException: The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cache.CachingStore.CachingStoreProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cache.CachingStore, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.**

I have made sure that this test passes locally on my dev machine. On TFS, drop folder, I ensure that DLL is there. I looked into the config that get deployed to build folder and they look correct and have the cachingstore entry. I reflected upon the deployed dll and it looks okay. the project build successfully on my machine and on the build machine. I don't know how to trouble shoot on why it works on my dev machine but does not work on the build machine.

It seems that project when deployed to build machine, is losing reference to the CachingStore dll. But why or how would it lose reference on the build machine? I also reflected on the project dll that gets deployed and it looks okay?

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another attribute on the tests that need the dll
e.g.

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("SomeAssembly.dll")]
public void MyTestForSomething()
{
...
}
```

Comment: this appears to be working on couple of tests.. I will try on others too. Thanks Tony !!!!!!!